# Import data series from a txt file in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, readfile

Hello I have data series in a txt file like structure below. How do I import the contents of this file in MATLAB? (`{}` is cell)

input:

```
Date,code,OPEN,HIGH,LOW,CLOSE,VOL
20081206,IDXS,9248.80,9248.80,9167.80,9178.30,8539624
```

output:

```
{Date} {code} {OPEN} {HIGH} {LOW} {CLOSE} {VOL}
{20081206} {IDXS} {9248.80} {9248.80} {9167.80} {9178.30} {8539624}
```

Comment: try something like https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/20836-csv2cell

Comment: @abbas Did any of the answers below help you?

Answer (score 2):

If you want everything in cells, you can do the following in releases prior to R2019a:

```
>> t = readtable('table.txt');
>> c = [t.Properties.VariableNames; table2cell(t)]
```

Since R2019a:

```
>> c = readcell('table.txt')
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your data is saved in the fle `dat.txt`, then you can try the following code. Here are two approaches:

- if you are using Matlab R2019:

```
text = readcell('dat.txt');
```

- if you are using lower version of Matlab or Octave:

```
fid = fopen('dat.txt');
C = textscan(fid,"%s");
text = cellfun(@(x) strsplit(x,","), C{:},"UniformOutput",false);
fclose(fid);
```